error: class MultiselectItemBinding is public, should be declared in a file named MultiselectItemBinding.java

error: class MultiselectItemBinding is public, should be declared in a file named MultiselectItemBinding.java

i cannot be solve this issue, and cannot change the file name because its inbuild file.
i tried change the file name, but cannot be change the file name in android studio project.

/Users/esakkiammal/Documents/Timecard-Android/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/out/com/technogems/timecard/databinding/MultiselectitemBinding.java:17: error: class MultiselectItemBinding is public, should be declared in a file named MultiselectItemBinding.java
public final class MultiselectItemBinding implements ViewBinding {


Are you on a file system that ignores case, like MacOS? Then renaming with only a case change (e.g., a.java -> A.java) won't work as it's the same file name according to the file system.
Rename in two steps, first to a temporary name, then to the real name. For example, rename a.java to foo.java, then rename foo.java to A.java.
See also How do I commit case-sensitive only filename changes in Git? in case you work with git.
